# Removing elements from the DOM that were added through JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have tried to lookup for an answer to this but I have not been able to find an answer.

In my project, I add HTML by using JS.

```
let winnerHTML = 'this HTML will appear in the dom when a condition is met'

const gameCont = document.getElementById('game-container');
const decideWinner = () => {
  if ( spadesPosition === 90 ||
     heartsPosition === 90 ||
     clubsPosition === 90 ||
     diamondsPosition === 90 ) {
     gameCont.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", winnerHTML);
  }
};
```

Now I want to remove that HTML, I've tried to set winnerHTML = ''; but clearly it's not the right logic. Since the added HTML is not part of the document, I can't select it and remove it.

Could you guys help me out here? My apologies in advance if there's already something about this but I didn't find it.

Cheers!

Comment: why are you saying the added html is not part of the document. You add it to `gameCont`, which is fetch from `getElementById`, so the added part is now in the DOM

Comment: It's `innerHTML`, not `winnerHTML`. Also wrap your text in `<span>` to later select it

Comment: @Justinas OP uses the variable hence `winnerHTML` is correct.

Comment: The added markup is part of the DOM. Use any of the `.querySelector*` or `.getElement*` methods or `.children` or ... to get it and remove it.

Comment: After adding to dom, it won't keep track of the variable in which you store the value. Keep a reference to the dom element and remove it when required

Comment: I've made it work, thanks a lot guys! @Prabhjot, I've used your advice and it's great, thanks a lot. I was misusing it, because I was selecting the elements before they were in the dom (that's why I was struggling). I changed it to select the elements when the function runs (it's a function that runs on click).

Thanks a lot everyone :D

Answer (score 2):

Add it to paragraph or span with id for later reference :

```
let winnerHTML = "<p id='para'>this html will appear in the dom when a condition is met<p>";
```

Then to remove it:

```
let elem=document.getElementById("para");
elem.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `document.createElement` and store the element in a variable. Then you can use the `remove` function to remove it. Example

```
let elem = document.createElement("p");
elem.innerHTML = "Your text";
document.getElementById('game-container').appendChild(elem);
elem.remove();
```

Comment: yes ! thanks for updating ; I have removed my comment, you may do the same for yours